# How to fix Pixel 6 pro emulator screen bug?

Tags: android, flutter, android-studio, android-emulator

My pixel 6 pro emulator, downloaded through android studio, has a very strange display. It looks as if the phone had been dropped and the display had been damaged. I have tried using different API images, and the result is the same. Any hints as to why this might be happening?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Please check the device frame settings for your emulator.

Sample **pixel_7_pro** settings.

[image: Device Frame Settings]